# bootstrap search rails look and feel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, search-box

I've got a nice bootstrap navigation menu with a search box in it.

I've got it in a partial file...

```
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

I like the layout of this search box.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get my rails search box to look the same...

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title_or_template_cont, "Search" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title_or_template_cont %>


</div>
 <div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Search" %>
```

What changes do I need to make in my rails form to look like the bootstrap search box?

I tried a few classes within the rails search box, but wasn't close to the way it looked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Checkout the gem "Simpleform" so you can style forms with css easily in rails using their helpers.  Then:

```
<%= simple_form_for @search, html: {class: "navbar-form navbar-left"} do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input_tag :title_or_template_cont, label: false, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}, placeholder: 'search' %>
  </div>
 <div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

Comment: oh, I've got simple forms already in my gem file.   I'll just try the code above.  Thanks.